# Moment date is rolling back to previous month

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a datetime coming from my api as `2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z`. This is `frame.scandate`.

I have another date which is generated within my program as `2018-09`. This is just `scandate`. These could be for any year/month combo, I am just giving examples.

My code looks like

```
    this.allStations.forEach(station => {
        station.frames.forEach(frame => {
            if(moment(frame.scandate).isSame(moment(scandate), 'month')){
                total+=frame.framesTotal;
            }
        })
```

This will match the previous `frame.scandate` with the the current `scandate`.

This:

```
scandate = '2018-09';\
frame.scandate = '2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z';
console.log(moment(scandate).format('YYYY-MM'));
console.log(moment(frame.scandate).format('YYYY-MM'));
```

will output this:

```
2018-09
2018-08
```

I fixed the problem by doing this:

```
    this.allStations.forEach(station => {
        station.frames.forEach(frame => {
            if(moment(frame.scandate).add(1, 'minute').isSame(moment(scandate), 'month')){
                total+=frame.framesTotal;
            }
        })
```

`.add(1, 'minute')` being the key change here.

Is this because the `frame.scandate` value has the `00:00:00Z` time value? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I get `2018-09` for both: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h9gdbeka/ I assume that due to your timezone, the date rolls back across midnight, ending up at 2019-08-31

Comment: Very interesting, I ran your fiddle and get the same answer as in my question: the rollback still happens. It could be due to my timezone then. Ill do some research, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably something going on with the timezones.

This script, ran in Spain

```
var moment = require('moment'); // This is because I've tested it in a nodejs environment
var scandate = '2018-09';
var result = moment(scandate);
console.log(moment(result).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Outputs `2018-09-01`

---

We could get around this by initializing `frame.scandate` like so:

```
frame.scandate = moment.utc('2018-09-01T00:00:00.000Z');
```

With `moment.utc()` instead of just `moment()` the output expectations are met.

Comment: Chris G answered something similar for me; his jsfiddle even gives him the correct answer while giving me the wrong one. I'll do some research then report back.

Comment: It's definetely timezone stuff; `Date` data is stored at a milisecond precision (unix time) and then it's represented back to the user accordingly to its timezone. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate it. I answered my question up above using moment.utc() to initialize my moment object. If you want to copy my answer text and put it into yours, Ill mark this as "answered".

Comment: Go ahead and delete your answer; edit mine and I'll accept the edit